# Cannot Compile RenderScript on Eclipse

Tags: android, renderscript

I have similar case as mentioned on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55342 and stated FIXED.

But I still cannot make it works. I have updated SDK Tools to 22.0.5 (latest). SDK Platform Tools to 18.0.1 (latest) and SDK Build Tools 18.0.1 (latest).

But still I got Error executing Renderscript. Please check llvm-rs-cc is present at "D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\llvm-rs-cc.exe"

What did I miss? Can someone point me out?

Comment: Have you re install the adt plugin from eclipse, Install new software?

Comment: What working directory is the compiler being executed from? Is this the expect directory?

Comment: @kamil, yes I have updated to ADT 22.0.5 already.

Comment: @Gusdor, I have D:\eclipseHelios64 and D:\Android\android-sdk-windows and D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34

Comment: @kamil. Thanks for your pointer. Yes, I forgot to update the ADT to 22.0.5. I did only update SDK Tools. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kamil. Thanks for your pointer. Yes, I forgot to update the ADT to 22.0.5. I did only update SDK Tools. Now everything works fine.